# Unable to print MATLAB data in new row in EXCEL

Tags: database, excel, matlab, output

I am trying to get this data to present itself into a new row each time a result is obtained. However, I am only getting one row in Excel as of now.

--> I Guess the thing I am being unable to do is that, once one data point is entered /written, matlab needs to **AUTOMATICALLY** goto the next line/row ... which it is currently not doing.

Any help appreciated,

---

```
figure;
prices_pred = zeros(size(prices));
prices_pred(750) = prices(750);

time_show = 15000;

for t = 750:length(prices)-1    
    price180 = prices(t-179:t);      
    price360 = prices(t-359:t);      
    price720 = prices(t-719:t);

    dp = theta0 +  theta(1);

    prices_pred(t+1) = prices(t) + dp;

    if (t-750 < time_show)
        x1 = 0:t-750;
        y1 = prices(750:t);
        x2 = 0:t-749;
        y2 = prices_pred(750:t+1);
    end
    if (t-750 > time_show)
        x1 = 0:time_show;
        y1 = prices(t-time_show:t);
        x2 = 0:time_show+1;
        y2 = prices_pred(t-time_show:t+1);
    end
    plot(x1,y1,'b*',x2,y2,'m*');

    drawnow;
    disp(prices_pred(t+1));
    disp(prices(t));
    disp(dp);

    if (T > 750)
        T = {T;table(prices_pred(t), prices(t),dp)};
    else
        T = table(prices_pred(t), prices(t),dp);
    end
    filename = 'test.csv';

    writetable(T, filename);
```

Comment: First of all, I can't reproduce your program in due to a lot of unknown variables. Please, create [mcve]. 
second - I not really read  your mindfully, but you can use `Range` parameters for Tables. And then you can write your table to specific part of the sheet. And the last one - are you really need to use Tables? why you don't want to use `xlswrite` function?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to write to Excel is by using a cell array and the `xlswrite` command.

With the variables given below, the steps for that would be as follows...

Variables:

```
eventDate = [{'2016-02-10'};{'2016-02-11'};{'2016-02-12'}];
eventTime = [931;931;1600];
eventValue = [{'open'};{'open'};{'close'}];
xlsDir = 'c:\xls\';
xlsFilename = [xlsDir,'output.xls'];
```

1) preallocate your cell array:

```
nevent = length(eventTime);
xxcell = cell(nevent+1,3);
```

2) create the headerlines for your cell array:

```
irow = 1; icol = 1;
xxcell{irow,icol} = 'Date'; icol = icol + 1;
xxcell{irow,icol} = 'Time'; icol = icol + 1;
xxcell{irow,icol} = 'Value'; icol = icol + 1;
```

3) Add your data to the cell array:

```
for ievent = 1:nevent
    irow = ievent + 1; icol = 1;
    xxcell{irow,icol} = eventDate{ievent}; icol = icol + 1;
    xxcell{irow,icol} = eventTime(ievent); icol = icol + 1;
    xxcell{irow,icol} = eventValue{ievent}; icol = icol + 1;
end
```

4) write to Excel:

```
try
    xlswrite(xlsFilename, xxcell);
catch
    disp('xlswrite error');
end
```

I haven't tried using the `writetable` command, but this method works well enough.